# Is the gluon also a repulsive force?

Tags: nuclear-physics, protons, strong-force, gluons

[image]

In the picture of a proton we see 3 quarks, held together by gluons. But the two $u$ quarks repel each other , so the gluons act through the strong force, whereas the $u$ and $d$ quarks attract each other, if all this is correct, then what keeps them a part? can a gluon also act as a repulsive force?

EDIT: there is something that escapes me, if the answer is correct :"* at a certain distance the force becomes repulsive*". Presumably, the distance between U-U and U-D is the same, so why in one case it repels and in the other attracts?

Comment: Why would you think they are repulsive? It is the EM force that causes the up quarks to repel, and if the gluon was repulsive ilthe proton wouldn't be stable.

Comment: D and U quarks have opposite charge and attracts each other, right? they surely need a repulsive force to keep then apart? right?

Comment: Protons and electrons also attract one another and yet atoms are stable, no need for an extra repulsive force. But imagine squeezing those charges that close together, have you tried to do a rough calculation of the electric force at those distances?

Comment: Like in the proton and electron in hydrogen, it's the uncertainty principle that keeps them apart. The electron in hydrogen is in an L=0 state with zero momentum, and so are quarks in lowest energy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Description of force inside the nucleons (between quarks):**

The strong force is pretty weird, we can't even compute exact solutions for it in quantum field theory (that is the most accurate description for interactions or particles/fields).

So we compute it in limits, such as the limit when the distance becomes small or big, but we can't compute all the exact values as the distance increases and show it as a function (in the first image you can see an approximation of what data from the accelerators tells us, but mathematically can't be exactly computed).

What we found in 1973, was that the attractive colour force (strong force mediated by gluons) actually gets weaker as quarks get closer together. This is called asymptotic freedom (quarks tend to get free as we approach lower distance scales [higher energy scales]). Since quarks become non-interacting at short distances, there is no need for a force to keep them apart, you can see better this in the following image, where the colour charge can be interpreted as the strength of the force.

[image]

In the other limit case, we found that there is what we call confinement, which is that when we separate the quarks (higher scale distance/lower scale energies) the attractive colour force essentially approaches a high constant value, keeping them together or then at some higher distance the gluon force disappears because particle-antiparticle creation is possible for which one takes the previous position of our original now separated quark, and the other gets in a bound state with our separated particle :)

[image]

You can see now why they are called gluons, they don't let the quarks be alone, they are always glued to more quarks!

**Description of force between nucleons (not between quarks):**

Now we can say that there is a remanent of the interaction between quarks with gluons, that radiates outside the nucleon (proton or neutron), which then makes protons and neutrons interact, attracting them and binging them together in the nucleus. But this residual force keeps them at a distance, not like the electric attractive force, which always wants to make them closer and closer and closer.

It can be seen and understood way better if you see this graphic of the corresponding forces. Where you see that the residual strong force starts repulsive, and at a certain distance around the separation of nucleons, becomes attractive.

You can also see that the residual strong attractive force in its peak is way bigger than the repulsive electric one, which means that its effect dominates, fixing the particles at a concrete distance. Or in the case of the opposite electric charge particles, when the electric force tries to take them together too much, then the strong force becomes repulsive and again fixes them at concrete separation.

[image]

**Edit: Extra images from [Visualizations of Quantum Chromodynamics (hyperlink)](http://www.physics.adelaide.edu.au/theory/staff/leinweber/VisualQCD/Nobel/)**

Simulations of the "quantum soups", where you can see it is going to be more complicated than balls interacting:

[image]

Simulations of what is called the flux tubes showing the gluon field, formed between quarks in meson states (pair quark-antiquark) or nucleons (three quarks):

[image]

where you can see these flux tubes tend to minimize their length uniting the three quarks together in one "Mercedes" sign flux. (In these last simulations they have fixated the form and the positions of the quarks, where in reality, again they would be more complex soups oscilating).

Comment: To answer your edit, the real deal is way more complicated as anna said, you don't really have 3 balls (quarks) inside a bigger ball (nucleon) interacting, what you do have are soups of quantum quark fields oscillating in a complicated way attracting and repulsing in all points. Some possible arguments to why don't opposite charge quarks become clumpled together is that there are virtual quarks-antiquarks creating and annihilating that makes "neutral screens" to colour and electric interaction and that you have to take into account that into the complicated quantum quark soup oscillating.

Comment: You can also try think this even with the balls picture, and a bit of statistic. In your image for example, the strong interaction is attractive, and the electric interaction between U-D is also attractive, so why don't they go together, what keeps them appart? Well you have two U's for example, so the D quark would feel force to both direction, to which one it goes? Why choose one over the other? The one that is closer maybe? But again the quark really is not a point particle, is a field occupying a volume, so some part will be closer to one and some to the other.

Comment: I don't understand when you say `Or in the case of the same electric charge particles, when the electric force tries to take them together too much`.  Same charge particles repulse, so how could the electric force be trying to bring them together?

Comment: @Michael it was a pretty evident typo, ma bad. But if I was talking first about same charge repulsive, and then I change to same charge attraction, I think you have deduced it hehe. Fixed it!

Answer (score 7):

Lets start from experimental facts. The proton exists and is stable. This means that at the quantum level there must be one stable wave function a solution of the complicated potentials of both the electromagnetic and the strong force. The proton is even more complicated than your picture as there are innumerable quark-antiquark and gluon pairs in its makup.[See this article:](https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/largehadroncolliderfaq/whats-a-proton-anyway/)

[image: proton]

The mathematical complication is modeled with [lattice quantum field theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_QCD), with which the higher bound states of the nucleon have been successfully modeled, for [example see the figures](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.7805) here.

My basic point is that the proton is a quantum bound state of its constituents, as are the higher mass states of the [baryon octet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eightfold_way_(physics)#Baryon_octet) and decuplet. The proton is stable because it is the lowest energy state.

Comment: stable it is, can you explain in simple terms why in one case it is repulsive? is distance the key factor? do the many virtual pairs affect the force between valence quarks?

Comment: As the other answer tries to explain, it is a combination of potentials, electric, magnetic, strong, and as you see in the image in my answer of very very many virtual particles and their potentials. It is only with the collective model of QCD on the lattice that a quantum stable solution can be found

Comment: "in one case it is repulsive?"  this is the classical picture of forces. The proton can only be described with a stable  quantum mechanical solution. It is one of the main reasons quantum mechanics developed.